Magento 2: override .phtml file in a custome module
I am new to Magento 2 and I'm not quite understand its structure yet. I'm using its sample data to investigate code. I want to override a .phtml file by using a custome module. The file I want to override is:
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml
So far, I create a file in this path:
src/app/code/NewModule/NewModuleTest/view/frontend/templates/customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml
I copy that original file to this and make some simple changes like add a  tag, changing text. After that, I run command:
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:clean
But nothing happen. I don't know if I'm missing anything. I also clear browser's cache. Please help me. Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you all!
P/s: I don't know if this is related, I install Magento by this repo on Github: Docker Magento

I figured out how to do this
Identify files you want to override

Original template file:

vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml

Original layout file:

vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml

Original block inside layout file (where this template is assigned to):

<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="Magento_Customer::account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false">
    <container name="customer.account.dashboard.info.blocks" as="additional_blocks"/>
</block>

Override steps

Create a layout file with the same name with the original name:

app/code/NewModule/NewModuleTest/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml

Put code with referenceBlock tag and original block’s ‘name’

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_info" template="NewModule_NewModuleTest::customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>


Create the template .phtml file: /app/code/NewModule/NewModuleTest/view/frontend/templates/customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml

Then it's done!

You need create a layout file to update this .phtml template, like this:
NewModule/NewModuleTest/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_dashboard_index.xml

and add this content:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">NewModule_NewModuleTest::customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>

The customer_account_dashboard_index.xml file targets the specific page you want to modify. It uses the  tag to modify the customer_account_dashboard_info block, setting the template to your custom .phtml file

This looks exactly what I asked on ChatGPT. But it didn't work T.T

Do you necessarily want to use a custom module ? If it's only  css / js / .phtml you can just create a custom theme and extend Magento default theme.

Yeah. I want to use custom module. Because with this, I can simply provide that to customers
